# Wordpress theme reverted back automatically

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have theme Sydney by ATHEMES activated on my Wordpress site http://www.hamrolagi.com, and edited the theme files without making a child theme. I had edited the header.php, template-tags.php and other templates files according to the customization requirement. It was working fine until yesterday, but today I see that the edits I had made to the files were reverted, and though the site is still functioning, the customizations are lost, except that to the template-tags.php, which is the only file I had edited which was not in the main theme directory. I had backed up the edited files. So, I was able to re-edit them, but I wanted to know what caused it and how to prevent it in future?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it was a theme update. Always use child themes - that is by far the only sure way to prevent it from happening in the future.

Comment: I checked the theme's web page. There is no update since a month.

Comment: I hear you, but since your code changed, it had to come from somewhere and it could only be done by update'ing. Reverting could not happen by itself because it would have no data to use.